# Visual Studio - Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

[image: Error screenshot]

I'm getting this error during starting debug.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this issue by editing the `launchSettings.json` file in the startup project and removing wildcards from the `applicationUrl` value

Comment: Problem is that you need wildcard sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using auth0 and I hadn't updated the Auth0 keys in the appsettings.json:

```
"Auth0": {
    "Domain": "CHANGE ME - https://manage.auth0.com/dashboard/ > Applications > Domain",
    "ClientId": "CHANGE ME - https://manage.auth0.com/dashboard/ > Applications > Client ID",
    "ClientSecret": "CHANGE ME - https://manage.auth0.com/dashboard/ > Applications > Client Secret"
}
```

Y replaced all of these values with the ones provided by Auth0 and worked like a charm!